Control unit for 600W 12V DC camper water heater
I'm trying to build a 12V DC hot water tank for my camper.
The aim is to use excess energy supplied by my 350W PV panels to heat water using a 600W heating element that is split into two connectable 300W heating coils.
My idea was to run one 300W coil automatically when the battery (200ah LiFePO4 12V) is almost full, thus the voltage is above xV and the water temperature is below y°C.
Additionally, I want to be able turn on both coils manually when needed and also be able to shut off the entire system when required.
The plan I designed has an

on/off switch
followed by a temperature-controlled relay
followed by a switch between a voltage-controlled relay going to one coil or just an on position for both coils.

The signal would control a relay closing the circuit for the 25amps (1 coil) or 50amps (2 coils) directly from the battery / PV to the heating element.
Between the 50 amp connection to two coils and the 25 amp connection to just one coil would need to be diode so the power from the voltage-controlled relay doesn't go to both coils.
The reason I want to separate 1 or 2 coils is that the one coil can run (almost) fully without draining the battery each time and therefore shutting on and off often.
600W is for when I "quickly" need hot water regardless of battery level.
This system should work but is quite complicated, space demanding and a bit pricey.
Instead of decoupling the coils, is it possible to leave them connected and control the wattage going to the coils? Can a 300W 12V coil run on fewer amps (just not as hot) or on a different voltage?
Do you have any ideas on how to make it simpler / better / different?
Thanks in advance,
Simon


Welcome, please provide a picture of your plan, as it's currently hard to understand how you want wire things up

Note that your diode will consume 20 watts at 25 amps.

Thanks for pointing this out Marla! I didn’t know and that’s indeed a lot. I think I need a different solution. Do you have any ideas?

@HansmitmFlammenwerfer  I added a picture.
I need a control line and an additional power line that’s turned on by the relays, because the temperature and voltage sensing units cannot handle the amperage. I have a 4 pin and a five pin relay to switch between off/option1/option2. Do you know of a relay that can switch between three options? Or generally a better idea of how to do it?
